How to Fill Holes in Porch Columns?
There are quite a few of these, about 1.25” (That’s a guess, not actual measurement) I’m concerned about insects nesting in there and wondering about the best way to fill them, in place. There is nothing on the back side of the hole that would allow me to firmly press putty in. TIA!



So the holes go through the posts?

Looks to me like the "posts" are a sheathing of maybe 1/2" thick wood.  Unclear if there's a structural column inside, or if that sheathing is it.  OP, can you clarify?

I've added another photo.  Yes, "sheathing" would have been a more accurate word. Thank you. I assume there is a structural column inside.  The holes do not reappear in the sheathing on the opposite side of the structure. They end in the sheathing cavity.

Firstly, ask yourself what those are for. Obviously they were left for a reason. They could be ventilation holes to reduce decay. It may be unwise to fill them.
You don't necessarily need a backer to use a filler material. The key is to press a bit of the material into the sides of the bore to ensure good contact. Then when you fill the hole completely you get a good bond.
1½" is pushing it as far as size for just filler, but it's worth a go. You might sand the bore a bit to degloss or remove the paint.
If they are that big, consider floating some 1" slats as backing secured with 1" trim-head screws. You can do this by putting a screw in the center of the slat as a handle. Then position and pre-drill for the mounting screws.
If your solution is to simply bug-proof it I'd look for some small soffit vents and fit them.

hmmmmm. That is a good question.  Do you know what they might have been intended for? My concern is that wasps or other insects will consider them to be an inviting home. I would imagine that, originally, if airflow had been intended, there would have been a screen placed on the inside. But I can't imagine how to add them now, since the interior is no longer accessible.

A square of window screen mesh can be stapled to the outside then painted white (make sure you tap the mesh over the holes to get the paint out). It won't be quite as ideal as if it had been installed from the inside but it will A) keep bugs out and B) be hidden from all but the most inquisitive inspectors (i.e. most people won't notice it at a glance).

@isherwood That is stunningly obvious, so much so that I missed it. Solution ordered. Thank you!

You're welcome. I see that none of your questions have been resolved yet. Please take the [tour] and then follow up on them as appropriate.
